# Facebook in iPad: UIWebView - renders as touch instead of standard web

Tags: facebook, uiwebview, iad

Up until a few days ago it worked fine: opening facebook.com in iPad/UIWebView rendered as standard web. Now Facebook is force-rendered as touch - as if the URL was http://touch.facebook.com. This happens regardless of the UIWebView frame size. Here is a simple code for the main view controller to see the problem:

```
UIWebView *wv = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com"]];
[wv loadRequest: req];
[self.view addSubview: wv];
```

I tried changing the user agent as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478387/change-user-agent-in-uiwebview-iphone-sdk) - no good.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. This code opens the regular frontpage on my iPad.

Comment: When you login and see the wall - does it render as standard web?

Comment: To add more info, no when I login and view the group wall the page is still in the Touch version of facebook.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue either, can you provide more details on steps reproduce?

Answer (score 1):

Using http://www.facebook.com?m2w should resolve this. "m2w" sounds like it is short for "mobile 2 web", and it's the link that you arrive at when you click "full site" from the mobile site.