# Modify the URL of the request in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ipad, redirect, uiwebview, basic-authentication

I tried what is described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478387/change-user-agent-in-uiwebview-iphone-sdk). Even though I was able to change the URL of the request, but the original URL was still loaded.

What I am trying to do is to insert an authentication string into the URL (i.e. http://user:pass@url) for those that don't already have it.

The URL I'm loading has frames, so the `[[webview request] URL]` inside `webViewDidStartLoad:webview` is always the parent URL, i.e. the url that contains the `<frameset>` tag. That makes it hard to check whether the modified request was actually processed.

Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: I should add this is for iOS3.2 (iPad).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One hacky solution I found is to use javascript:

```
[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: 
  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"location.href='%@'", newURL]];
```

In my case, the site has frames, so I set frames[1].location.href instead.