# How can I remove value that was previously registered via [NSUserDefaults registerDefaults:] call

Tags: cocoa, nsuserdefaults

I have bunch of preference values registered via `[NSUserDefaults registerDefaults:]` call on application startup. I need to replace them at some stage with new ones but new values scope (keys set) is less than initial one. So after I call `[NSUserDefaults registerDefaults:]` again I have new values with some old that weren't replaced. Is there a possibility to remove previously registered values?

Comment: If you're working on iOS, the docs(http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) mention that "The contents of the registration domain are not written to disk; you need to call this method each time your application starts. You can place a plist file in the application's Resources directory and call registerDefaults: with the contents that you read in from that file." So I assume that, if you leave them out, they are left empty. Do you have any idea why the old values are left in the defaults?

Answer (score 13):

**To completely replace the registered defaults**, you will replace the `NSRegistrationDomain` domain (which is volatile, by the way).

**To remove individual registered defaults**, you get the values in the `NSRegistrationDomain`, remove the offending key(s), and replace the domain.

A category on `NSUserDefaults` might look something like this:

```
@implementation NSUserDefaults (UnRegisterDefaults)

- (void)unregisterDefaultForKey:(NSString *)defaultName {
    NSDictionary *registeredDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] volatileDomainForName:NSRegistrationDomain];
    if ([registeredDefaults objectForKey:defaultName] != nil) {
        NSMutableDictionary *mutableCopy = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:registeredDefaults];
        [mutableCopy removeObjectForKey:defaultName];
        [self replaceRegisteredDefaults:[mutableCopy copy]];
    }
}

- (void)replaceRegisteredDefaults:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setVolatileDomain:dictionary forName:NSRegistrationDomain];
}

@end
```

**Motivation:**

The reason I need this is because I want to [turn on user-agent spoofing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18110039/1580288) (for reasons of 3rd-party compatibility). User-agent spoofing only appears to work when the value is set via `registerDefaults:`, so `set...:forKey:` won't stop the user-agent string it. If I want to stop spoofing the user-agent some time later (without restarting the app), I need a way to remove defaults. Further, I don't want to clear the other registered defaults my app users. The above solution appears to accomplish this perfectly.

Comment: Coincidentally ran into the exact same problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Great stuff. You should put that on GitHub. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3 port of EthanB's original answer:

```
extension UserDefaults {
    /// Unregisters a value set in the UserDefaults.registrationDomain, if it exists
    func unregister(defaultsFor key: String) {
        var registeredDefaults = volatileDomain(forName: UserDefaults.registrationDomain)
        registeredDefaults[key] = nil
        setVolatileDomain(registeredDefaults, forName: UserDefaults.registrationDomain)
    }
}
```

Used in `deinit` of my `UIWebView` to restore the default user agent back to my app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `removeVolatileDomainForName:` to remove the `NSRegistrationDomain`. This clears all values registered via `registerDefaults:`. But if you  need to do this you’re most likely doing something wrong. The right way would be to actually store the new settings using one of the `set...:forKey:` methods.

Comment: This solution won't fix my issue due to removeVolatileDomainForName works in level+1 stage than defaults