# UIWebView not showing the wikipedia search bar

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I am using UIWebView to provide a simple browser in an app.  When I go to Wikipedia the search bar at top of the page (mobile version) is never shown in the UIWebView.  Scrolling down and back up does not make it visible.

I tried both cases (YES/NO) for scalesPageToFit but did not do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Wikipedia is reading the user agent string and deciding not to show the search bar. (UIWebView's user agent is slightly different than mobile Safari's user agent.) Unfortunately, [it looks like you cannot change the user agent string used by UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478387/change-user-agent-in-uiwebview-iphone-sdk).