# Can you view websites with the iPhone SDK? And do different user-agent strings affect Safari CSS rendering?

Tags: css, iphone, layout, mobile-safari, user-agent

I'm trying to figure out some layout issues with Safari Mobile 3.1.1. – I want to know whether or not I can view sites with the SDK before I commit to installing it on my Mac.

My other dumb question is… does changing the `user-agent` string used by desktop Safari have any affect on how it renders CSS?  I understood that the UA string just announces which browser version is behind the request.

Answer (score 1):

I've never had a problem with either of those two things.

The UserAgent string isn't intrinsic to the version of the WebKit library, I don't think -- you can install a webkit build alongside the OS Safari and it'll work fine:

http://nightly.webkit.org/

... if you embed a UIWebView in your app, you can use whatever UserAgent string you like ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478387/change-user-agent-in-uiwebview-iphone-sdk)).

Comment: Thanks for your response. So you can view Safari mobile with the SDK.  Can you change versions?

Comment: NP. Do you mean on the device? -- it sounds like it's related to your UserAgent issue, are you sending different code to different iOS browser versions?

Comment: Well, I'm not sending different code yet.  I'm wondering if the SDK is capable of changing browser versions. I want to test webpages for Safari mobile.

Comment: Whenever I test for mobile safari, I use iphoney - http://www.marketcircle.com/iphoney/ ... the SDK itself doesn't give you access to historical versions of the WebKit engine by itself.