# detecting UIWebView with Javascript

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile, uiwebview, mobile-safari

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [detect ipad/iphone webview via javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460205/detect-ipad-iphone-webview-via-javascript)

I'm trying to determine wether my page is being viewed on iPhone's Safari, or through any other app that's capable of browsing the web (i.e. uses UIWebView).

Can anyone think of a way to do that?