# Force link in uiwebview to open in Safari - with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iphone, uiwebview, mobile-safari

This has a lot to do with my previous question:
[detecting UIWebView with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417007/detecting-uiwebview-with-javascript)

I would like to force a link on my webpage to be opened with iPhones actual Safari Browser, and not in a UIWebView window, even if the app it's being viewed in tried to open all links in a UIWebView window to prevent users from going out of it.

Please note that this is not a duplicate as I'm trying to do this with Javascript/Client-side, not within my own native app (I own the page that's being viewed, but can't control which app is used to view it).

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this is possible. I set up one of my apps to use a UIWebView only and never open Sarfari (though admittedly I allowed only pages within a certain domain).