# Determine and bind click or "touch" event

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, iphone, mobile

I'm using the below code to bind "click" or "touchstart" events (using jQuery's [`on(eventType, function() { ... })`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)).

```
var what = (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) ? 'touchstart' : 'click';
```

Later on:

```
$foo.on(what, function() { ... });
```

... which works great for iPad and "everything else", but I'm concerned that the above code has "iPad tunnel vision"...

**My question(s):**

Do all other devices (for example, Android tablets) have similarly named "touchstart" events? If so, how can I improve the above code so that I can account for those event types?

In other words, how can I account for a wider range of touch devices in above code (not just iPad)?

---

## EDIT #1

What do you folks think about this:

```
var foo = ('ontouchstart' in window) ? 'touchstart' : ((window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof DocumentTouch) ? 'tap' : 'click');
```

Note: Most of the above logic is [from Modernizr here](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/modernizr.js#L420-446).

The above appears to work for Firefox/iPad... I don't have much else to test on at this time.

What I like about the above is that I'm not UA sniffing. :)

Is `tap` a good default for all other touch devices?

---

## EDIT #2

Some [interesting information here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/854), which links to this:

[Creating Fast Buttons for Mobile Web Applications](https://developers.google.com/mobile/articles/fast_buttons)

Not a direct answer really, but gives a lot of details of the situation devs face when facing click-related events for multiple platforms and devices.

---

## EDIT #3

Some [good info here](http://backtothecode.blogspot.com/2009/10/javascript-touch-and-gesture-events.html) too:

> ### Android and iPhone touch events
>
> Android and iPhone versions of WebKit have some touch events in common:
>
> ```
> touchstart - triggered when a touch is initiated. Mouse equivalent - mouseDown
> touchmove - triggered when a touch moves. Mouse equivalent - mouseMove
> touchend - triggered when a touch ends. Mouse equivalent - mouseUp. This one is a bit special on the iPhone - see below
> touchcancel - bit of a mystery
> ```

After reading that, I think I'll change the code above to this:

```
var foo = (('ontouchstart' in window) || (window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof DocumentTouch)) ? 'touchstart' : 'click';
```

When I first asked my question - not having access to anything other than an iPad/iPhone - I assumed `touchstart` was an iOS-specific event; it now looks like `touchstart` and `click` will cover most, if not all, of the bases for touch devices.

---

## August 2014 update:

If it's of any help, I've posted some utility classes here:

- [mhulse / no-x.js](https://gist.github.com/mhulse/4704893):

  > [no-js] [no-touch] JavaScript utilities to put in  of HTML templates that will add `js` or `touch` classes for use in CSS and/or JS.

Comment: What happens when you bind multiple events? `$foo.on('touchstart click tap etc', function() { ... });`

Comment: Based on this question, it looks like `var what = (/(iPhone|iPod|iPad).*AppleWebKit/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? 'touchstart' : 'click';` might cover more bases.

Comment: @AdamMerrifield Thanks for the reply! That's a great question... Is `tap` what other devices use? Would there be any drawbacks to binding multiple events at once (perhaps, checking `e.type` could get a little squirrely... and what about performance issues?) Still though, it's a good idea/question... **I wouldn't mind getting away from UA sniffing.** Hmmm, I need to test some; I'll be back with my findings. Thanks!!!

Comment: Above, when I say "based on this question", I meant to link that text to [this question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460205/detect-ipad-iphone-webview-via-javascript).

Comment: For what it's worth, I found a list of events, and some interesting code, [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/js/events/touch.js): `touchstart, touchmove, touchend, tap, taphold, swipe, swipeleft, swiperight, scrollstart, scrollstop`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both iOS and Android have touch events, but Windows uses MSPointer events in IE. If you want a cross-device solution, try pointer.js or learn from it:

https://github.com/borismus/pointer.js

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for the tips and help; I'm checking out the code now.

Comment: It looks like pointer.js is now deprecated in favor of this pointer events polyfill https://github.com/jquery/PEP (based on W3 pointer events standard).

Answer (score 14):

I would strongly suggest against using UA in order to determine whether you're under touch environment.

Use Modernizr instead: http://modernizr.com/
The below code would recognize anything but windows phone 7 because the windows phone 7 does not fire the regular browser touch events. However WP8 would most probably be recognized correctly.

```
if (Modernizr.touch){
   // bind to touchstart, touchmove, etc and watch `event.streamId`
} else {
   // bind to normal click, mousemove, etc
}
```

Comment: Thanks for tips! I completely agree with you about UA sniffing. In this case, I'm writing a jQuery plugin and I would like to avoid having Modernizr as a dependency. OTOH, I really really appreciate you providing a code example (+1). Coincidentally, I'm currently using a slightly modified version of [this Modernizr code](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/modernizr.js#L420-446) to detect if it's a `touchstart` or `click` (see edits #1 and #3 in my original question above).

Comment: also don't forget to consider devices such as Microsoft Surface (or many Windows 8 laptops) that have both touch AND mouse, and in the case of Surface a stylus too. i.e. don't *disable* behavior based on 'touch' existing without careful thought

Answer (score 12):

This may work for you:

```
var clickEvent = ((document.ontouchstart!==null)?'click':'touchstart');
$("#mylink").on(clickEvent, myClickHandler);
```

Comment: Thanks! Good for iOS and desktop.

Comment: @DenysVitali can you explain?