# Detect if button touched or clicked

Tags: javascript, button, click, touch

Please bear my ignorance.

I have a page with one button on it:

How to detect if the user clicks (on a computer) or touches (smarthone, tablet) this button?

I read the answers of this quite similar question but the solutions involves using advanced and comlicated libraries. I am just a beginner: d you know how to do this in simle JavaScrit or jQuery ?

[Determine and bind click or "touch" event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11406285/determine-and-bind-click-or-touch-event)

Thank you all.

Comment: `element.onclick = function() { ... }` or `element.addEventListener('click', function() { ... })` with pure JS

Comment: I know that, but how to detect if the button if **clicked** or **touched**. Touched on smartphones and clicked on a computer @AndrewL.

Comment: My last example shows what you need :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use jQuery!
var deviceEvent = ((document.ontouchstart!==null)?'click':'touchstart');
$("#mylink").on(deviceEvent ,function(){alert('click true!');});

Answer (score 0):

**JAVASCRIPT**

With your button use

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Then write your myFunction() in `<script>` in javascript. like this

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
alert('Button clicked');
}
<script>
```

Read more here

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

**JQUERY**

Inlcude the jquery.js in your file then give button an ID then use a script.

Button:

```
<button id="submitbutton">Submit</button>
```

Jquery

```
$( "#submitbutton" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Submit button clicked!." );
});
```

**TOUCH OR CLICK JQUERY**

But from what I know, the problem you can face here is the touch. Here is a code that could make for touch or click

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#submitbutton').on('click touchstart', function() {
      alert( "Submit button clicked!." );
    });
});
```

Jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/0xdLjvtu/

Comment: Than you but your answers shows shows only how to deal with button clicks. My question is how to detect if the button is **clicked** or **touched**

Comment: Look at the very last example, it has the touched code too :)

Comment: @Mr. Lister thank you for adding the backticks, I didn't know that. :)

Answer (score 0):

you could try to use a variable for this if you would like, maybe try

```
<script>

    var buttonTouched = 0;

    function anyFunc01() {
       buttonTouched = 1;
    }

    function anyFunc02() {
       if(buttonTouched == 1) {
          console.log("button01 has been clicked at some point");
       }
    }

</script>

<button onclick="anyFunc01()">button01</button>
<button onclick="anyFunc02()">button02</button>
```