# Conditional javascript statement to target native UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, uiwebview, conditional-statements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [detect ipad/iphone webview via javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460205/detect-ipad-iphone-webview-via-javascript)

I need to disable a script on our mobile site when accessed from a native mobile app webview.

Is there a javascript conditional statement that I can use to target the iOS UIWebView from the client side?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460205/detect-ipad-iphone-webview-via-javascript

Comment: This is not possible without using userAgent strings.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution, thanks to @nivas :

var is_uiwebview = /(iPhone|iPod|iPad).*AppleWebKit(?!.*Safari)/i.test(navigator.userAgent);