# How to detect an in-app browser in iphone and android?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, mobile-browser

I'm working on a mobile site right now. But it performs a little bit different in a normal mobile browser and an in-app browser(when you scan the QR code or click a link in a social network app, for example). I use `navigator.userAgent.match(/ipad|ipod|iphone|android/i)` to detect mobile site and run corresponding javascript function, so I guess maybe this detection method doesn't work in in-app browser. Is there a universal way to detect all the mobile browsers including in-app one?

Comment: In-app browsers generally use the same browser framework that the stand-alone browser uses, with no reason to send anything to the host indicating a difference. You might be able to generate heuristics about screen sizes for the full size browsers and assume other sizes are an in-app browser, but this will not be accurate in all cases, especially Android in general.

Comment: Try ("ontouchstart" in window && "onorientationchange" in window)

Comment: `navigator.userAgent.match(/android/)` will also detect mobile chrome browser which is not expected result. Every in-app browser have special string in their `userAgent`. For example, 'FBAV' for facebook, 'KAKAO' for kakaotalk. I think the optimal solution at this moment is that list up those special string for target in-app browsers.

Answer (score 2):

There are user agent string variations even for in-app browsers. You can sometimes use those to detect specific in-app browsers: for instance, the Facebook on both iOS and Android contains the string FBAV (possibly short for Facebook Application Version?).

A working general solution for iOS is here: [detect ipad/iphone webview via javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460205/detect-ipad-iphone-webview-via-javascript)

I'm not aware of a general solution for Android.