# How can I detect if a user is viewing my site within an iOS UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, user-agent, passbook

I'd like to offer users using the slower, limited UIWebView a different experience than the native Mobile Safari users. How can I detect these users as distinct from regular Mobile Safari users?

Answer (score 2):

The user agent string will not contain `Safari`.  Answered here:

[detect ipad/iphone webview via javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460205/detect-ipad-iphone-webview-via-javascript)

Comment: Apparently in iOS 7, both UIWebView and Safari include `Safari` in their user agent strings. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: @Ryan Did you find a solution for iOS 7? I'm in the same pipeline.