# How do I detect a ipad/iphone webview in user agent using regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex

All I need to do is to convert the following Javascript regex test to Python:

```
var is_ios_app = /(iPhone|iPod|iPad).*AppleWebKit(?!.*Safari)/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/about) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: I am merely asking the same question as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460205/detect-ipad-iphone-webview-via-javascript but I couldn't find any good solutions anywhere on the interwebs to do the same thing in python.

Comment: I think the most basic thing to do would be to look for how python uses regular expressions yes? That would have led you to [this page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) using google, detailing all the different functions you can use and how to use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `re.search()` for this in Python.

```
userAgent = "YOUR_UA"
pattern = '(iPhone|iPod|iPad).*AppleWebKit(?!.*Safari)'
if(re.search(pattern, userAgent)):
    print "true"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is python library which can use for that purpose.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/httpagentparser

Example Usage:

```
>>> import httpagentparser
>>> s = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) \
        Chrome/5.0.307.11 Safari/532.9"
>>> print httpagentparser.detect(s)
{'dist': {'version': '2.3.5', 'name': 'Android'},
'os': {'name': 'Linux'},
'browser': {'version': '4.0', 'name': 'Safari'}}
```

So you can use **name** element of **dist** to get ios users.