# Add iPhone-detection to jQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css

I've written a script in jQuery, which adds padding to an element when my website loads as a web app:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery("div").ready(function(){
        if (("standalone" in window.navigator) && window.navigator.standalone) {
            jQuery(".menu-secondary").css("paddingTop", "20px");
        };
    });
</script>
```

I'd like to extend the script to only apply when the website is loaded as a web app on an iPhone or iPod.

I've tried the following with no luck:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery("div").ready(function(){
        if (("standalone" in window.navigator) && window.navigator.standalone) ||
        ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iphone|ipod/i))) {
            jQuery(".menu-secondary").css("paddingTop", "20px");
        };
    });
</script>
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Fix the syntax errors...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460205/detect-ipad-iphone-webview-via-javascript

Comment: If I could identify them, I wouldn't be wasting your time, buddy!

Comment: Is paddingTop standard jquery or do you have to use padding-top in js?

Comment: paddingTop works fine - as I mentioned, the issue is with the userAgent condition in the second script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

window.navigator.userAgent.match("iPhone")

this returns an array you should check for null or length

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how to do that

Comment: var array = window.navigator.userAgent.match("iPhone");

if(array!=null && array.length == 1) { }