# Is it possible to know if page is accessed from Browser / Mobile / Tablet

Tags: jquery

I have this simple HTMl file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
<p>Click me away!</p>
<p>Click me too!</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to know from which device this page is accessed from , i mean from Browser OR a Mobile / Tablet ??

I am sorry if this not related to Jquery section .

Comment: possible duplicate of [detect ipad/iphone webview via javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460205/detect-ipad-iphone-webview-via-javascript)

Comment: For styling purposes, google "CSS @media rules"

Answer (score 0):

Check out user agent in javascript :) OR use some already made script - check the site: http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/