# Detect twitter app webview by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, webview

I'm currently using the following codes to detect webview according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460205/detect-ipad-iphone-webview-via-javascript)

```
var is_uiwebview = /(iPhone|iPod|iPad).*AppleWebKit(?!.*Safari)/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
```

It works perfectly on Fb app but not twitter app. Please help.

Comment: Try logging what the user agent string is when viewed using the twitter webveiw.

Comment: @evolutionxbox is the same as the browser, sadly.