# HTTP requests from iPhone UIWebView and iPhone Safari / PC / Mac 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services, http

I'm quite a newbie on HTTP and client and server stuff.

On the server side, is there a way to tell the difference between HTTP requests sent from "iPhone UIWebView" and "iPhone Safari / PC browsers / Mac Browsers", given that I the programmer don't add extra fields to the iPhone UIWebView request?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, since UIWebView's send a user agent akin to the one send with Mobile Safari. Last I checked, there wasn't anything noticeable that differed between the two, though that could've changed. Try sniffing the HTTP requests with a tool like Wireshark and see if they differ.

Comment: Also want to add that you *can* modify the User-Agent for your own UIWebView, if, for some reason you want to be able to differentiate between the two. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478387/change-user-agent-in-uiwebview-iphone-sdk

Comment: Ah, yes! That's an awesome way to tell web view requests from within your own app...