# UIWebView: 502 Bad Gateway response

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I have been loading UIWebViews with a set of URL's for a long time while testing my app with no problem. Now I get `502 Bad Gateway` Error message when I load my UIWebView.

The URL's I use all came from the same source and all start with:

`http://www.gijon.es/eventos/show/`

Some URLs are for example:

`http://www.gijon.es/eventos/show/21514-ciclo-ciencia-x-cine`
`http://www.gijon.es/eventos/show/20611-mercado-ecologico-y-artesano`

- I have tested the URLs from my browser and they work Ok.
- I have tested doing a Log that this are actually the URLs just before creating the request.
- I have made a testApplication with just a UIWebView loading this URL's and it fails the she way my app does.
- Any other URL like `http://google.com` loads nicely.

How can I debug this problem? Should it be a problem with the remote server? Can it be a problem in my configuration?

Comment: This is a remote server error and is not associated with your code...

Comment: Why the URL does load in my browser but not in iOs app running in Simulator?

Answer (score 1):

The website is configured to handle requests differentely according to the browsers user agent.

So when you access it with UIWebView you are sending as a user agent iPhone, which takes you to a different page on the site.
Due to miscofiguration from their webserver you are seeing a 502 Bad Gateway error (probably they are running NginX).

To verify this, open Firefox, download the User Agent Switcher addon, select as a user agent iPhone 3.0, then open http://www.gijon.es/eventos/show/21514-ciclo-ciencia-x-cine

You will see the 502 bad gateway error

If you want to solve this, you can modify the default UIWebView user agent (set it to safari something). [The way to do this is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8666438/312312)