# UIWebView set user-agent at run time

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UIWebView iOS5 changing user-agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487581/uiwebview-ios5-changing-user-agent)

There is requirement to open some website in desktop version and some in mobile version. how to set different user agent in UIWebView's delegate 'webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType'.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Refer [allow-overriding-of-user-agent-on-uiwebview](https://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/06/radar-allow-overriding-of-user-agent-on-uiwebview/) link.

Refer [iphone-ipad-get-user-agent-for-uiwebview](http://blog.sallarp.com/iphone-ipad-get-user-agent-for-uiwebview/) link

Also refer [uiwebview-ios5-changing-user-agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487581/uiwebview-ios5-changing-user-agent) SO link.

Comment: Prince thanks for reply. is it possible to change user agent at run time?

Comment: yes it possible to change user agent at run time in - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)aWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

Comment: - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)req navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)Type
{
    NSString *url = [[req URL] absoluteString];
    NSString *userAgent = [url rangeOfString:@"yahoo.com"].location != NSNotFound ? @"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_2) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.77 Safari/535.7" : mUserAgent;
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:userAgent, @"UserAgent", nil];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];
    return YES;
}

Comment: is there any problem in this code?

Comment: is this safe for App Store acceptance? thanks!

Comment: Yes its app store safe to change user agent in UIWebView