# iOS: How can I get a UIWebView to load non-mobile sites?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

How can I get a `UIWebView` to load non-mobile sites?

Currently I'm using this:

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSURL URLWithString:websiteLink];
 [request setValue:
      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Safari/528.16", [request valueForHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"]]  
      forHTTPHeaderField:@"User_Agent"];
 [webView loadRequest:request];
```

but the app crashes when loading the web view.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Basically you need to change the user-agent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487581/uiwebview-ios5-changing-user-agent/8666438#8666438

Comment: what error are you getting when the app terminates?

Comment: He is doing it wrong. He needs to change the user-agent the way I showed in the provided link

Comment: This implies the app works with some URLs and not with others?  Apps do not terminate because you load a non-mobile page, so there is some other issue.  My 2 cents - changing the user agent is unlikely to "fix" this. After you correct the crash bug, you can try setting [self.myWebView setScalesPageToFit:YES]; to make non-mobile pages look better.

Comment: So i just need to create a NSDictionary? , @Dave i have done that in storyboard inspector view "SetScalesPageToFit" do i need the code anyway?

Comment: post the console log and the exact error message.

Comment: @Jon, nope, setting in Storyboard works just as well.

Comment: Error Message: http://jonathangurebo.tumblr.com/post/40521720109/error-message

Comment: sorry it was to many characters

Comment: @JonathanGurebo You should edit your post and add it to that, not as a comment. **That** is your crash.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the user-agent in your request:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setValue:@"<Your-User-Agent>" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
```

Where  can be something like:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Safari/<version number>", [request valueForHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"]
```

### EDIT:

My User-Agent string is like:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/536.26.17
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.2 Safari/536.26.17

Please note that **webservers usually cache informations such as your browser information**, so if you have visited the site already the code above might not work.

Comment: the app will not terminate when using a little bit of your code. but instead i comming to a non-touch-mobile-website. i'm using: NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url34];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Mozilla/5.0", [request valueForHTTPHeaderField:@"<User-Agent>"]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"User_Agent"];

Comment: but what should i set instead of <Your-User-Agent> ? what User Agent should i use?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation. http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006517-SW3

Comment: I tested some of the code in the document but i didn't find a solution, Please, can you give me the exactly code i should use? i'm a beginner.

Comment: its not working, i use: NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url34];
    [request setValue:@"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/536.26.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.2 Safari/536.26.17" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
    [webView loadRequest:request];

Answer (score 0):

According to the error (in the picture you added), you're calling a selector that doesn't exist. Specifically, calling `valueForHTTPHeaderField:` on `request` (which is an NSURL) is invalid because NSURL doesn't respond to that method.

Comment: its not working, i use: NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url34]; [request setValue:@"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/536.26.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.2 Safari/536.26.17" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"]; [webView loadRequest:request];

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan,

It's been a few days, but in case you are still looking for the answer to this - the problem is right here:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSURL URLWithString:websiteLink]; // <-- BUG
```

Your are stuffing an NSURL into a MutableURLRequst.  Oops!

This is what you intended to do:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:websiteLink]];
```

Good luck.

Comment: its not working, i use: NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url34]; [request setValue:@"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/536.26.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.2 Safari/536.26.17" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"]; [webView loadRequest:request];

Comment: Fixing that line should absolutely prevent your crash.  You should not need to change your user-agent header, but if you insist the best way is to change it in userDefaults.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487581/uiwebview-ios5-changing-user-agent  Just setting it as you are only changes it for the 1st request, and not all the subsequent requests that the webpage will make.