# How to set a custom user-agent for an osx webview using swift

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, webview

I'm having trouble setting a custom user-agent for my webview in the demo I am just trying to set it to my Safari user-agent. It is seemingly very difficult to find examples of how to go about doing this in a swift based osx cocoa application.

Here's my code:

```
import Cocoa
import WebKit

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressIndicator: NSProgressIndicator!

    override func viewDidAppear() {
        super.viewDidAppear()

        self.view.window?.titleVisibility = .Hidden
        self.view.window?.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
        self.view.window?.styleMask |= NSFullSizeContentViewWindowMask

        let urlString = NSURL(string: "http://whatsmyuseragent.com")

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(["UserAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/600.7.12 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.7 Safari/600.7.12"])

        self.webView.mainFrame.loadRequest(NSMutableURLRequest(URL: urlString!))
    }

    override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
            // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

    override func webView(sender: WebView!, didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame frame: WebFrame!) {
        self.progressIndicator.startAnimation(self)
    }

    override func webView(sender: WebView!, didFinishLoadForFrame frame: WebFrame!) {
        self.progressIndicator.stopAnimation(self)
    }

    override func mouseEntered(event: NSEvent) {

    }

}
```

Also I have seen [UIWebView iOS5 changing user-agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487581/uiwebview-ios5-changing-user-agent) the code example given seemingly does not do anything and/or I am putting it in the wrong place. I have 2 files "AppDelegate.swift" and "ViewController.swift" I have tried the code at various places in both files to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIWebView iOS5 changing user-agent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487581/uiwebview-ios5-changing-user-agent)

Comment: Have you tested it after writing this code `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(["UserAgent": "Mozilla/.....2"])`  in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` ?

Answer (score 1):

The important properties for this are `WebView customUserAgent:` and `WebView applicationNameForUserAgent:`.

To replace the entire User-Agent string with a new one:

`webView.customUserAgent = "MyAgent/1.0.0"`

To append your app string onto the existing user agent string:

`webView.applicationNameForUserAgent = "MyAgent/1.0.0"`

Further details:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/Tasks/Spoofing.html