# Google calendar OAuth API 403?

Tags: ios, calendar, google-api, swift3, google-calendar-api

I want to fetch events from google calendar 
First I Tired  Authenticate by Google API and follow all steps and end by this error 
[image]

After Few Search convert code to google SDK 
on this https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/

and Authenticate successfully

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!,
          withError error: Error!) {
    if let error = error {
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(
            name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "ToggleAuthUINotification"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
    } else {
        // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
        let userId = user.userID                  // For client-side use only!
        let idToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
        let fullName = user.profile.name
        let givenName = user.profile.givenName
        let familyName = user.profile.familyName
        let email = user.profile.email
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(
            name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "ToggleAuthUINotification"),
            object: nil,
            userInfo: ["statusText": "Signed in user:\n\(fullName)"])
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
    }
}
```

every think working well but the problem in the after Authenticate i want to access calendar and get events https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/ios

```
    - (void)fetchEvents {
  GTLQueryCalendar *query = [GTLQueryCalendar queryForEventsListWithCalendarId:@"primary"];
  query.maxResults = 10;
  query.timeMin = [GTLDateTime dateTimeWithDate:[NSDate date]
                                       timeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];;
  query.singleEvents = YES;
  query.orderBy = kGTLCalendarOrderByStartTime;

  [self.service executeQuery:query
                    delegate:self
           didFinishSelector:@selector(displayResultWithTicket:finishedWithObject:error:)];
}
```

each time give me 403 error and I can't find any solution of SDK to solve this, so any Suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/40591090/1841839

Comment: It's not duplicate please read it well I solve the 403 error by sdk in sign in my problem is calendar if it have sdk or something solve the problem

Comment: If you have a fix for user agent disallowed please add anwsers to the three or four out standing questions about it

Comment: What is the 403 error you are getting now? If not disallowed?

Comment: Just follow this link https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/ no 403 and sign successfully but it authorized through GIT and calendar take authority from GTM in API

Comment: Your question is unclear exactly what is the error with your code?

Comment: i have answered it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40591090/403-error-thats-an-error-error-disallowed-useragent