# Google OAuth Client with Angular/Ionic: How do I find the redirect_uri?

Tags: angular, ionic2, google-plus-signin

I have an `Ionic2` app that I would like to add [`GooglePlus Authentication`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/google-plus/) to.

I get the following error:

[image]

As far as I understand, it's because I have not set up a `redirect_uri`.

**Question**

What `redirect_uri` (`Authorized redirect URIs`) should I use for an Ionic2 app? Where do I find it?

[image]

The following works with `Facebook` login.

[image]

**UPDATE**

Following [these](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus) instructions, I changed the `REVERSED_CLIENT_ID` to the following format:

```
"com.googleusercontent.apps.uniqueId"
```

So I think I have made progress.

I now get the following error in `iOS`:

[image]

From reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42269251/google-400-error-invalid-request-custom-scheme-uris-are-not-allowed-for-web-c), this means that the `credentials` should not be created for a `Web Application` [here](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient). But if I create it for `iOS`, how will this work for `Android`?  Or does `Android` not make use of these credentials anyway?

For `Android`, when I try to log in, I just get an exception with an `undefined` error message.

So I have **two questions** please:

1. Do I need to create `iOS` **client ID** [here](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient) instead of a `Web application`?

[image]

2. How do I configure or debug this for `Android`?

**UPDATE**

For `iOS` I added an `iOS Client Id` and changed my REVERSED CLIENT ID to match, and like with `Android`, it prompted me to sign into my Google Account. So that looks like further progress.

However, once I sign in, like with `Android` now I get an exception with the message as `undefined`. In the `Xcode` console, however, I do get the following:

> com.google.HTTPStatus error 400.

Following [these](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158849?hl=en#installedapplications&ios), I have now created credentials for both `iOS` and `Android`.

[image]

I have configured `Android` and `iOS` IDs in the new IDs.

I get an **exception** with the message as `undefined` on both `Android` `and` iOS.

**UPDATE**

Got it working for `iOS`.  The `webClientId` option when you call `login` must not be the reversed client id, but rather the client id.

```
        GooglePlus.login({
            'webClientId': 'xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            'offline': true
        }).then(googleData => {
```

Now to figure out why `Android` doesn't work.

In Android, I now get `error = 12501` (which is a result of something wrong with my Keystore I think).

**UPDATE**

I generate the Keystore. As per [these](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth) instructions, I copy the `SHA1` to the `Signing-certificate fingerprint`. But still get `error = 12501`.

[image]

Comment: Josh Morony wrote an article here on this. Perhaps it can shed some light for you: https://www.joshmorony.com/implementing-google-plus-sign-in-with-oauth-2-0-in-ionic-2/

Answer (score 1):

As you got iOS working, here is solution for `Android`.

Build APK of your app and then run this command-

```
keytool -list -printcert -jarfile app.apk
```

The output will reveal the `Signature`, `Certificate fingerprints (MD5, SHA1 and SHA256)` and `Extensions` of the APK.

Copy the `SHA1` to the `Signing-certificate fingerprint` while creating client ID for android