# Firebase Google Auth using iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have checked the CLIENT_ID and REVERSED_CLIENT_ID by re downloading GoogleService-Info.plist also gave the URL Types too but still getting the same error

[image]

Please help

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42269251/google-400-error-invalid-request-custom-scheme-uris-are-not-allowed-for-web-c

Comment: I have looked at it, but couldn't find the real cause. deleting the entire project is a no can do. @GustavoConde

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by looking at

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials

go to your app and find the credentials for iOS app

then change the CLIENT_ID and REVERSED_CLIENT_ID in your app accordingly

make sure you also update the URL TYPES in Info in Project Target