# React-Native: Google Custom scheme URIs are not allowed for 'WEB' client type

Tags: ios, react-native, wiki, google-signin

I am creating application in **React-Native** and it has **Google Login**. I research on it and I got [Google-React-Native](https://github.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin) from here. I added it and follow all the steps which it say. But I am still getting error. I spend two days behind it, but didn't get any solution.

I also follow [this-solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42269251/google-400-error-invalid-request-custom-scheme-uris-are-not-allowed-for-web-c), but my issue is still not resolved. Can any one help me to find the solution?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its a very small mistake. The issue is in generating key for Google. I follow below steps and generate new key and its work for me.

1) Open “**https://console.developers.google.com**” and generate one application.

2) You will get three menu on Left size. Click on “**Credential**” tab.

3) You will get new window with three option. “Credentials”, “OAuth consent 
screen” and “Domain verification”.

4) Click on **Credentials** and then "**Create Credentials**" from it.

5) Click on **OAuth Client Id** and fill information. You will get the one key.

Use it into your application and it will work fine.

Hope these steps will help to other guys also.

Happy Coding

[image]