# Google drive integration in swift disallowed_useragent error

Tags: swift, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am trying to integrate google drive api in my swift project what i want to do is get files from drive and upload it to my server.
I have tried to implement using the google documentation and stuck on a **error: disallowed_useragent**.
I have seen that embedded web views are deprecated i have to use OS browser but i am not been able to so.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why can't you use a `WKWebView` and load and perform this operation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [403 Error - Thats an error. Error: disallowed\_useragent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40591090/403-error-thats-an-error-error-disallowed-useragent)

Comment: @SachinVas I don't where to initialise the webview and provide it drive service

Comment: DalmTo all the solutions are specific to objective c only. I am looking for something in swift

Comment: Try converting the same with the swift first.

Comment: i have answered it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40591090/403-error-thats-an-error-error-disallowed-useragent in swift