# How can I fix impaired functionality caused by disallowed useragent?

Tags: ios, google-oauth, user-agent, wkwebview

I'm building a web browser an recently I came across an error while trying to login using my Google account on a website.

[image: Screenshot]

This is strange because I checked the user agent of my app and Safari's and they are both identical.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

The WKWebView is nested 3 levels deep inside a tree of custom UIViews.

Here's the initialization code:

```
_webView = [[WKWebView alloc] init];
_webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = NO;
_webView.allowsLinkPreview = NO;
_webView.navigationDelegate = self;
_webView.UIDelegate = self;
_webView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.contentView.frame.size.width, self.contentView.frame.size.height);
[self.contentView addSubview:_webView];
```

Comment: can you please show some code ?

Comment: I added the initialization code. I don't know what else to add.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Google [Modernizing OAuth interactions in Native Apps for Better Usability and Security](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html) article:

> On April 20, 2017, we will start blocking OAuth requests using web-views for all OAuth clients on platforms where viable alternatives exist.

So, Google now allows sign-in with Google Account only in normal browsers, it restricts it in web-views due to security reasons and recommends Google SDKs for [iOS](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/) and [Android](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/) for this purpose.

But if you still want to use `WKWebView` you may do a little trick, suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42386804/1948606) answer, setting `customUserAgent` so it can pass validation:

```
// Check for selector availability, as it is available only on iOS 9+
if ([_webView respondsToSelector:@selector(setCustomUserAgent:)]) {
    _webView.customUserAgent = @"MyCustomUserAgent";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your rich response. I was not working all this time sorry for the delay! I changed it to an arbitrary value and t's working fine.