# How to fix impaired Google Login/Signup on WKWebView?

Tags: ios, google-oauth, user-agent, wkwebview

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44344720/how-can-i-fix-impaired-functionality-caused-by-disallowed-useragent) a few weeks ago which I thought would have solved the problem with Google Login/Signup but it is still broken.

1. Open getpocket.com
2. Click on Log in now>
3. Click on Log In with Google

When you enter your email and password and click next the page becomes blank and nothing happens. No redirects, no loading, nothing.

In Safari the page redirects and login happens successfully.

I have tried Google Login with stackoverflow.com and it works!

But I believe it is using a different method because it doesn't ask me for anything, login just happens. It doesn't even ask me to select which account I want to login with. Everything happens automatically.

Normally, if you had entered your email and password Google asks you to select which account you want to use to login without having to enter the information again.

With getpocket.com this screen appears, I click my account and it freezes. An orange loading bar animation plays without end.

I can't understand what is the problem.

Could it be the user agent?

Any ideas?

The initialization of the WKWebView is very basic:

```
_webView = [[WKWebView alloc] init];
_webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = NO;
_webView.allowsLinkPreview = NO;
_webView.navigationDelegate = self;
_webView.UIDelegate = self;
_webView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.contentView.frame.size.width, self.contentView.frame.size.height);
[self.contentView addSubview:_webView];
```

I have even tried a popular web browser [iCab Web Browser](http://www.icab.de) and the problem is still there with getpocket.com

Answer (score 0):

Here are some researches I gathered:

1) https://www.whatismybrowser.com/developers/tools/user-agent-parser/browse/browser-name/icab-user-agents -- Latest iCab has iCab user agent.

2) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent#User_agent_spoofing -- iCab has the feature of "user agent spoofing". When you request oAuth2.0, your oAuth request is controlled by Google Play Service. If Google Play Service doesn't have iCab user-agent, then Google Play uses default user-agent and ultimately from the server, your iCab browser get the HTML body of redirection page. During that time, iCab again matches user-agent. Here, iCab finds different user agent, thus, it blocks the page loading.

I checked from Chrome, everything was running. So, possibly it should be the problem because of user-agent.

https://udger.com/resources/ua-list -- In this site, I read iCab uses webkit user-agent.

I am not sure exactly, but there is high chances because of **user-agent spoofing** features, it is creating problem.

Comment: Maybe you are right. I'm using this user agent: "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/14F89 Safari/602.1"

Answer (score 0):

> Google's announcement is clear: “In the coming months, we will no
>   longer allow OAuth requests to Google in embedded browsers known as
>   “web-views”, such as the WebView UI element on Android and
>   UIWebView/WKWebView on iOS, and equivalents on Windows and OS X.”

src: [theregister.co.uk](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/08/23/google_to_block_web_views_from_using_its_oauth/)