# Google Tasks error 403 : Error :disallowed_useragent android

Tags: delphi, google-tasks

I am using Embarcadero RAD STUDIO 10.2 and would like to propose a Google authentification to connect on my Android application
I have an error 403 : Error :disallowed_useragent 
when I compile my application for android 
but not when I compile for windows 
Does anybody have had similar problem ? 
I cannot find how to modify the user agent for a Webform on Delphi FMX (not VCL)
Thank's a lot for your help :):)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40591090/403-error-thats-an-error-error-disallowed-useragent

Comment: https://blog.cloudrail.com/solving-disallowed_useragent-for-google-services/

Comment: Thank's a lot Rudy for your kindly help but now I have another question .... how to change the user agent of the Delphi TWebbrowser component. Because this component do not have userAgent property unfortunatly

Comment: I don't think you can. Doesn't the second link help you get around the issue?

Comment: No unfortunatly. I have found how to add User Agent for TWebBrowser component in Delphi but only for VCL application and not for FMX ( Android and IOS)

Comment: @PierreJean You'll need to modify the FMX source to do that. For Android, you'll need to call getSettings.setUserAgentString on the WebView. For iOS, you'll need to call setCustomUserAgent on the WebView. If you need more help than in a comment, it might pay to ask a separate question

Comment: @PierreJean Is **[this account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4173032/pierre-jean)** also yours? If so, you might want to see **[this help center page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)** for help on merging two accounts. Thank you.