# Firebase + Ionic3 Error: disallowed_useragent

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, ionic3, angularfire2

There are a couple of other questions/answers on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40591090/403-error-thats-an-error-error-disallowed-useragent), but they were not using Firebase with Ionic. I just switched to the new Ionic View and right now today, my app in the old Ionic View works while the new Ionic View gives me this well known error:

> 403 Error - Thats an error. Error: disallowed_useragent his user-agent
>   is not permitted to make an OAuth authorization request to Google as
>   it is classified as an embedded user-agent (also known as a web-view).
>   blah blah blah

In my code I inject the Firebase AuthProvider and use angularfire2 to connect and it looks like

```
  private getProvider(from: string): AuthProvider {
  switch (from) {
    case 'twitter': return new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider();
    case 'facebook': return new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    case 'github': return new firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider();
    case 'google': return new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  }
}

  signIn(from: string) {
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(this.getProvider(from))
. . .
```

Again, this works great in the browser or old Ionic but not the new Ionic View. I do have a fairly big library with general OAuth connections, but I thought that one of the great reasons to use Firebase is that we would no longer have to use those libraries and manage users ourselves.

Is there a way to do the Firebase auth on an iOS/Android app via Ionic?

Comment: Can you test on a real device?

Comment: No, I am not ready to make it into a stand alone app yet--I've only been using Ionic View so far but maybe I'll try that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63018705/getting-403-disallowed-useragent-on-azure-b2c-ionic-capacitor-inappbrowser-goo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should follow the instructions in [this article](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova). I don't think `signInWithPopup` method is supported, you should try `signInWithRedirect` instead.

I managed to fix the `disallowed_useragent` error by adding the following to my `config.xml`:

```
<preference name="OverrideUserAgent" value="Mozilla/5.0 Google" />
```

Comment: Only problem is that now, platform will be detected as desktop. Presents a small problem for me, but you solved a huge one and I can now finally login with Google on Cordova. Thank you, thank you, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try this

`ionic cordova build android --minifycss --optimizejs --minifyjs`

solved for me

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest you to run this on the **real device** since Ionic view app has a lot of issues with native plugins and etc.

*CLI*

```
ionic cordova run android --prod --device
```

or

```
ionic cordova run ios --prod --device
```