# Firebase + Ionic + Cordova signInWithRedirect redirects to localhost on Android

Tags: android, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I have recently re built my Ionic app, after a series of updates, and `signInWithRedirect` stopped working **on Android**, and redirects to **localhost:8080** after login, while it's fine on iOS.

Here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...,
    "firebase": "5.4.2",
    "@angular/fire": "5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/firebase": "4.12.2",
    "cordova-plugin-browsertab": "^0.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-buildinfo": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-customurlscheme": "4.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase": "2.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "2.1.4",
    "cordova-universal-links-plugin": "git+https://github.com/andyepx/cordova-universal-links-plugin.git#b91b58fb8a7ff9f2b2de83b4adceece13e9cf2a8",
  },
  ...
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      ...
      "cordova-plugin-local-notification": {},
      "cordova-plugin-firebase": {},
      "cordova-plugin-browsertab": {},
      "cordova-universal-links-plugin": {}
    },
}
```

The version of `cordova-universal-links-plugin` I am using it's a fork of the original plugin, with a few fixes for Cordova 8.

In `config.xml`

```
<preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTask" />

<universal-links>
        <host event="openAppEvent" name="app.my.com" scheme="https" />
        <host name="myapp.page.link" scheme="https" />
        <host name="myapp.app.goo.gl" scheme="https" />
        <host name="myapp.firebaseapp.com" scheme="https">
            <path url="/__/auth/callback" />
        </host>
</universal-links>
```

And the login snippet I'm using:

```
// this.firebaseLogin is an instance of AngularFireAuth

return this.firebaseLogin.auth.signInWithRedirect(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider())
      .then(() => {
        return this.firebaseLogin.auth.getRedirectResult()
          .then(x => authCallback(x))
      })
```

I can't find what the issue with this configuration is, especially as it works perfectly on iOS...

Comment: For Cordova, Firebase Auth expects the current URL to be of the form `file://`. It looks like it is confusing this for a browser environment.

Comment: Hey @bojeil, that's what it seems like it's happening... But I can't figure out what changed in Cordova 8 that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 8):

With these versions:

```
"cordova-android": "^8.0.0",
"cordova-plugin-browsertab": "0.2.0",
"cordova-plugin-buildinfo": "2.0.3",
"cordova-plugin-compat": "1.2.0",
"cordova-plugin-device": "2.0.3",
"cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "3.1.0",
"cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.4",
"cordova-universal-links-plugin-fix": "1.2.1",
"firebase": "^5.9.4",
"cordova-universal-links-plugin": "~1.2.1",
"@angular/fire": "^5.1.2"
```

I was able to fix this problem by adding the following to my `config.xml`:

```
<allow-navigation href="http://*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*" />
```

Then however I got a 403 error: `disallowed_useragent` (similar to in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47237896/firebase-ionic3-error-disallowed-useragent)) which I managed to fix by adding the following line to `config.xml`:

```
<preference name="OverrideUserAgent" value="Mozilla/5.0 Google" />
```

Comment: In plain English, this answer says to stop using the Ionic webview. Until Firebase adapts to the way Ionic webview works, or until the Ionic webview stops running an integrated server. If it ever happens.

Comment: @LouisAmeline how do you mean, will the app work without Webview plugin? I just removed and installed older version and it crashes(white screen)

Comment: @EmreAkkoc On Android, don't use Ionic's webview plugin and the default system webview made available by Cordova will be used automatically. And just FYI, not exactly related, but for iOS you (currently, until Cordova makes it default) have to specify in your config.xml that you want to use Cordova's official WKWebview plugin. For your bug, I suggest you delete your plugins folder, clean your package.json and rebuild, it often fixes things.

Comment: thank you for explanation. and it worked by the way

Answer (score 3):

After further exploring, and following @bojeil suggestion above, turns out that
`cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@latest` runs an integrated webserver, at `http://localhost:8080` which doesn't work with how the Firebase SDK looks for Cordova / handles redirects.

So, the working solution  for now is to use `"cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "1.2.1"` and hope that Firebase will solve this issue in the upcoming versions of their JS SDK.

I have also raised this issue here https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1244

Comment: Thank you for this!. Sadly for me that plugin does not work when I build the apk, do you know if there could be any other workaround ?