# Getting 403 disallowed_useragent on Azure B2C + Ionic Capacitor InAppBrowser google login

Tags: ionic-framework, azure-ad-b2c, capacitor

When I try to click the google login on Azure B2C login page it redirect me to to another page with the error 403 disallowed_useragent.

This is what I tried so far:

Add Try to add the `overrideUserAgent` as in the [documentation](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/basics/configuring-your-app) mention.
Adding this line at the root of the capacitor.config.json

```
 "overrideUserAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 Google"
```

I also try to add the UserAgent [plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/user-agent)
I add this line in my app component to set the user agent

```
this.userAgent.set('Mozilla/5.0 Google')
        .then((res: any) => console.log('UserAgent test' + res))
        .catch((error: any) => console.error(error));
```

And at the end I also add in the config.xml this line

```
<preference name="OverrideUserAgent" value="Mozilla/5.0 Google" />
```

Any of those solutions work when I debug the inAppBrowser console log I see this result in the request header

```
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 11; sdk_gphone_x86 Build/RPB1.200504.020; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/83.0.4103.44 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solve it by adding the `overrideUserAgent` to the capacitor.config.json  like this

```
  "cordova": {
    "preferences": {
      "OverrideUserAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 Google"
    }
  },
```

This object was added to the root of the file.

The problem is that Cordova preferences are added to capacitor preferences when we run `cap init` command, After that to add Cordova preferences we should use Cordova object inside capacitor.config.json as I did above.
https://capacitorjs.com/docs/cordova/migrating-from-cordova-to-capacitor#cordova-plugin-preferences

Comment: upvoted. thanks a lot. your solution worked on my angular project. it's not specific to azure actually

Comment: @stackunderflow I have the same problem but with web application. Is your angular project web app or mobile app? How do you fix it? Thank you.