# FirebaseUI iOS App - Google sign-in 403. Error:disallowed_useragent

Tags: ios, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

using this article to implement single sign-in using FirebaseUI https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/firebaseui

All other authentications are working correctly , when tried with Google email. Getting this error. Have setup URL Scheme correctly as mentioned in this article.

Tried on iOS 8.1 and 11+ getting same error on different simulators.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked REVERSED_CLIENT_ID in URL Schemes

Comment: are you using safari or other browser?

Comment: you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40591090/403-error-thats-an-error-error-disallowed-useragent

Comment: yes its default FirebaseUI, check it https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3659

Comment: what is the solution?