# How to use always the mobile version of the web

Tags: ios, uiwebview

So I have a little WebView in an iPad app, and I'd like to always show the mobile version of the web pages on the WebView. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think by default the websites check the user-agent of the browsers and redirect them to the suitable version of the website.

Comment: So can I change the user-agent?

Comment: From the default user-agent used by UIWebView, the website will know you are on iPad. So you don't need to change it if that's what you want, but if you still want to change it, then check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478387/change-user-agent-in-uiwebview-iphone-sdk