# Enable Cookies in UIWebView

Tags: ios, iphone, cookies, ios5, uiwebview

How can I enable cookies in my iPhone Application that uses a UIWebView Window, so that my login system will work?

Answer (score 9):

For sure start with

```
[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage].cookieAcceptPolicy = 
    NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways;
```

But, as mentioned by @JoelFan, the issue may be your User Agent string causing ASP.NET to attempt and fail at a cookieless login. Instead of a response that includes

> Set-Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=*really-long-hex-number*

it returns a redirection to something like

> Location: /(F(*long-sorta-base64ish-looking-string*))/

The default UIWebView user agent string is something like

> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_0_2 like Mac OS X)  AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/11A501

but ASP.NET doesn't like this. Safari sends something like this:

> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) **Version/7.0** Mobile/11A501 **Safari/9537.53**

Do the following early on, maybe in your AppDelegate.m

```
// DON'T try to reuse a UIWebView for this. 
UIWebView *wv = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
// This webview has already decided to use the default user agent string.

// let's use javascript to get the existing user agent string
NSString *userAgent = [wv stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"navigator.userAgent"];

// let's tack on some stuff to make ASP.NET happy
userAgent = [userAgent stringByAppendingString:@" Version/7.0 Safari/9537.53"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:@{@"UserAgent": userAgent}];
// New UIWebViews inited after here will use the user agent string you made.
```

Answer (score 1):

If the site you are logging into is an ASP.NET site, the problem may be due to the UIWebView sending an unrecognized User Agent.  See [Change User Agent in UIWebView (iPhone SDK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478387/change-user-agent-in-uiwebview-iphone-sdk)