# How to change window.navigator.userAgent value of UIWebView

Tags: ios, ios5, uiwebview

There are [several ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478387/change-user-agent-in-uiwebview-iphone-sdk) to change the user agent **header** send by UIWebView. However the value of *window.navigator.userAgent* retrieved by JS on any page always contains the same value, something like "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 4_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/8C134".

Is there any way to change that value without having to modify the HTML response (and insert some JS)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no way, as far as I know. However, instead of modifying the HTML response, you could use `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` to inject some Javascript code after the page has loaded.

Comment: @pgb thanks for your response! The problem regarding this is that I would need to create JS workarounds for each supported website. Isn't there any generic approach?

Comment: I don't think there is one. My suggestion -at least- allows you to inject the same JS code regardless of the HTML that comes back from the server.

Comment: @pgb but there isn't any place where the page has already been loaded but its JS hasn't been executed yet, is it?