# UIWebView and Safari renders differently

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a `UIWebView` which is adapted to a mobile style of a forum I have.  In Safari, it looks and works great.

However, inside my `UIWebView` there is a major problem.

When quoting or editing a post, HTML is displayed inside of `BBcode`.  Furthermore, posting code results in ignored line breaks.  This problem will render my app completely unusable.

The webview is loaded like this:

```
  //display the webview
    NSString *fullURL = @"http://www.mysite.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSMutableURLRequest *requestObj = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_webTest loadRequest:requestObj];
```

This is how it looks inside of mobile Safari (correctly)

[image]

And finally, how it looks inside of `UIWebView` (incorrectly)

[image]

What could possible be changing the way it renders between mobile safari vs `UIWebView`?  I thought the point was their supposed to look the same!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because mobile safari and a webview have different user agent values.
Check out this SO post which is about a similar issue: [Change User Agent in UIWebView (iPhone SDK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478387/change-user-agent-in-uiwebview-iphone-sdk)

Code from accepted solution:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)req navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = (NSMutableURLRequest *)req;

    if ([request respondsToSelector:@selector(setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:)]) {
        [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Safari/528.16", [request valueForHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"User_Agent"];
    }
    return YES; 
}
```

Comment: i changed the user agent but unfortunately the output is still the same.

Comment: try checking your webview and mobile safari against http://whatsmyuseragent.com/.  The code I'd posted may be slightly out of date.

Comment: actually, the code doesnt seem to be changing my user agent but i will look into this, thanks for the tip

Comment: Thank you propstrm - The instructions here got it working to future people: http://www.mphweb.com/en/blog/easily-set-user-agent-uiwebview