# Override UIWebView user agent - but not for Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, uiwebview

I'm setting a custom UserAgent for the webviews in my app as per the instructions in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478387/change-user-agent-in-uiwebview-iphone-sdk).  Specifically, I'm setting

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"MyApp/MyLongVersionInfoString", @"UserAgent", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];
```

at app launch.  (Just setting the appropriate headers for the NSMutableURLRequest to be used by the UIWebView - UserAgent, User-Agent, User_Agent - does not work.)

This causes my embedded webviews to use the correct user agent.  However, it also breaks the embedded webviews used by the Facebook SDK for dialogs - after I post to my wall, for instance, the contents of the FB dialog webview are replaced with *text* similar to `window.location.href="fbconnect:\/\/success?post_id=100002469633196_43677789308119...` and the webview does not close as it normally would (the user has to manually close it).  This only occurs when I have my custom user agent set.

I thought I could circumvent the problem by unsetting the user agent before Facebook calls and resetting it afterwards, but it seems I can't unset the default defaults; I tried calling `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"UserAgent"]` and `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:NSRegistrationDomain]` before each Facebook call and setting them again in the call's result handler, but I still see the same misbehavior.

I tried switching my initial settings to `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:newUA forKey:@"UserAgent"];`, but then *my* webviews don't pick up the user agent.

Surely, surely, someone has used the Facebook SDK before in an app with non-Facebook embedded webviews.  What am I missing?  I've gone a number of rounds on this, each of which seems to almost-but-not-quite fix everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up having to do this by implementing an NSURLProtocol subclass.  While my implementation was messy, I'm including a scrubbed version below because I was surprised not to be able to find an example already on StackOverflow.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyProtocol : NSURLProtocol {
    NSURLConnection *connection;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURLConnection *connection;

@end

@implementation MyProtocol

@synthesize connection;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark custom methods

+ (NSString *)myUA {
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"MyCustomUserAgent"];
}
+ (BOOL)canInitWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    NSString *scheme = [request.URL.scheme stringByAppendingString:@"://"];
    NSString *baseRequestString = [[[request.URL absoluteString] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:request.URL.path withString:@""]
                                   stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:scheme withString:@""];
    if (request.URL.query != nil) {
        NSString *query = [@"?" stringByAppendingString:request.URL.query];
        baseRequestString = [baseRequestString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:query withString:@""];
    }

    BOOL shouldIntercept = [baseRequestString isEqualToString:myWebHost];
    BOOL alreadyIntercepted = [[NSURLProtocol propertyForKey:@"UserAgent" inRequest:request] isEqualToString:[self myUA]];
    return shouldIntercept && !alreadyIntercepted;
}

+ (NSURLRequest *) canonicalRequestForRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    return request;
}

- (id)initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request cachedResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse client:(id<NSURLProtocolClient>)client
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *mutableRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:request.URL
                                                       cachePolicy:request.cachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:request.timeoutInterval];
    [mutableRequest setAllHTTPHeaderFields:[request allHTTPHeaderFields]];
    [mutableRequest setHTTPMethod:[request HTTPMethod]];
    if ([request HTTPBody] != nil)
        [mutableRequest setHTTPBody:[request HTTPBody]];
    if ([request HTTPBodyStream] != nil)
        [mutableRequest setHTTPBodyStream:[request HTTPBodyStream]];
    [NSURLProtocol setProperty:[[self class] myUA] forKey:@"UserAgent" inRequest:mutableRequest];
    [mutableRequest setValue:[[self class] myUA] forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
    [mutableRequest setValue:[[self class] myUA] forHTTPHeaderField:@"User_Agent"];

    self = [super initWithRequest:mutableRequest cachedResponse:cachedResponse client:client];
    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    [connection release];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark boilerplate NSURLProtocol subclass requirements

- (void) startLoading
{
    self.connection = [[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:[self request] delegate:self] retain];
}

- (void)stopLoading
{
    [self.connection cancel];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)conn didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse*)response
{
    [[self client] URLProtocol:self didReceiveResponse:response cacheStoragePolicy:[[self request] cachePolicy]];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data
{
    [[self client] URLProtocol:self didLoadData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)conn
{
    [[self client] URLProtocolDidFinishLoading:self];
}

- (NSURLRequest*)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest*)theRequest redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse*)redirectResponse
{
    return theRequest;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)conn didFailWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    [[self client] URLProtocol:self didFailWithError:error];
}

@end
```

Note that the protocol must be registered with `[NSURLProtocol registerClass:[MyProtocol class]];` before you make any web requests to which you want it to apply - for instance, in `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.