# What's the iPad User Agent of iPhone App when emulated in iPad in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview

Will a user agent of an iPad running an iPhone app with a UIWebView use a iPad User Agent, or an iPhone user agent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default User-Agent the UIWebView on iPad uses is:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/10B141
```

Yes, it is an iPad User-Agent.

You can check your User-Agent string by going to:

http://jonathangurebo.com/detect
or
http://whatsmyuseragent.com

if you wan't to change your User-Agent in UIWebView, check this link: [Change User Agent in UIWebView (iPhone SDK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478387/change-user-agent-in-uiwebview-iphone-sdk)

Comment: That is quite annoying. If the website within UIWebView contains adapted content for iPad, this will be displayed over the content for the iPhone. Which will likely cause the perceived page not to be displayed as expected.