# Display informative device type for login to Facebook from UIWebView

Tags: ios, facebook, uiwebview

Is there a way to change the Device Type displayed in Facebook security's active sessions when using a `UIWebView`? When you log in with the Facebook app, the display says "Facebook for iOS on iOS 6".

Is there some parameter I can pass or some setting I can tweak to change the displayed name here?

[image: Facebook Device Type]

Answer (score 0):

Its most likely based on the user agent. You can change the default user agent for your UIWebView like this: [Change User Agent in UIWebView (iPhone SDK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478387/change-user-agent-in-uiwebview-iphone-sdk)

Comment: This caused my the device type to read "unknown" with a [?] box that said the value I set. Very close. I wonder if there is something else to try.