# How to open a website on UIWebview as computer?

Tags: uiwebview, safari

On Google Chrome there is this option "Website for computer". Many websites recognize that your are using mobile phone and they redirect you to another website made for mobiles.

I just need to don't let them to recognize that I'm using a UIWebview from IOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine you can get this effect by [changing the user agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478387/change-user-agent-in-uiwebview-iphone-sdk?lq=1).

That should work with most web sites, unless they are really serious about trying to detect mobile devices (by checking window size, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Your user agent", @"UserAgent", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];
```