# Google Authentication - User agent gives error on WebView (Nylas api)

Tags: ios, swift, user-agent, wkwebview

We are using **Nylas api** to get Access token for different type of `Email account like Gmail, Outlook`.. But We couldn't authenticate for `Gmail`.

```
        let myURL = URL(string: getNylasAuthUrl())
        let userAgent = getUserAgentParams()
        webView.customUserAgent = userAgent
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
```

got below error

[image]

Finally found a way, by setting User-Agent, we could do authentication for gmail [from post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478387/change-user-agent-in-uiwebview-iphone-sdk)

Tried below User-agents but didn't help

```
let userAgent =  "Mozilla/5.0 (Apple \(Utils.getDeviceModel()) ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"
let userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"
let userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Google) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the working `user-agent`.

```
    let userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_2 like Mac OS X)
AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/14F89 Safari/602.1"
```

If you want to Google auth via Webview, use this `user-agent` especially for getting access token.